# C# write user defined string to web server location

Tags: c#

Can you kindly educate me in how can I see the string that I have created, written in the web server location, using c#.

The output I see in the file, that I write in the server location has only the "Date", "Time" and after 4 commas "my IP address"

somthing like this:  2013/11/12,00:20:56,,,,,x.x.x.x,

I would like to see my created string written in the places where we see the commas.

Here is my code:

```
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(""www.xyz.com/.../....MyUrlLocation");

// Set the Method property of the request to POST.
request.Method = "POST";

// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
string postData = Environment.UserName + "," + sw.Elapsed.ToString() + "," + NumberOFProperties.ToString();

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
//byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "PUT";

// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

// Get the request stream.
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
bool bIfCanWrite = dataStream.CanWrite;

// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close();

// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
string strLine = reader.ReadLine();

// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

// Clean up the streams.
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "written in the web server location" - do you mean in the HTTP logs?

Comment: Hi Jon, yes I mean, getting the script, written in the http logs. I wish to see the string get written up in the http logs

Comment: Then you'll have to change whatever's writing the logs. The *client* doesn't get to decide the log format.

Comment: Perfect Jon, I understand that. Honestly I am not even a beginner in understanding the, in core aspects of how it is supposed to work, but I understand that I do not have the control to do it. When I try doing it in Python, the  "urllib.request.urlopen( link )" , help me in writing the script as I intend it to do. For Example this is how it is seen .......    2013/11/11,05:09:29,shaktas,WINDOWS,Change_Volume_Stop,, x.x.x.x      You see that, it has the same format , and after the time it helps in getting the string also written. This is what I need to do too. sorry if I am missin on anything

Comment: Sorry, I found your comment too confusing to understand. But fundamentally you should work out what the format of the log line *is*, and then you can work out how to populate it.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I shall get to know the format and work it out. May be then I can populate it and see the information getting written.

Comment: Hi Jon, perfect. Should thank you on suggesting that I need to know the format of the log line. I got it working now.

Comment: Hi lump, ya sure I should be sharing the knowledge to all. The  only change in my code is to add in the information in the string :    string postData = "http://x.y.z.com/cgi-bin/CusageWebScript.pl?Iso_mount_Tool" + "," + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString() + "," + NumberOFProperties.ToString() + "," + Environment.UserName.ToString(); -----and then call -----HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postData.ToString());    So have the log format in mind, and then populate your string and then call the HttpWebRequest create, to get your data written in the specified server log.